# storing & loading your apps previous state

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-developer-api

I am using static session_counter to store the data,
yes the data I want to retrieve when app is opened is a INTEGER

```
 private static int session_counter = 0;
```

MY app state
[image]

AFTER USER PERFORMED AN ACTION THE SESSION COUNTER SHOWS 1,
BUT WHEN THE APPLICATION IS CLOSED AND RE-OPENED AGAIN THE COUNTER IS SET TO 0

I WANT THAT SESSION COUNTER TO BE THE SAME AS PREVIOUS STATE TILL THE SPECIFIC CONDITION IS MET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For applications such as this you need a way where you can persist the data between each session.
as a previous answer mentioned shared preferences is the most effective way to do it.

Other alternatives exist as

1. Room
2. A remote database (Firebase) etc.

The structure will be somewhat like this

````
```

// Create object of SharedPreferences.
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);

        //now get Editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        //put your value
        editor.putString("session_value", required_Text);

        //commits your edits
        editor.commit();

       // Its used to retrieve data
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
       String name = sharedPref.getString("session_value", "")

       ```
````

In your case it will be like

```
textView.text= sharedPref.getString("session_value", "")

if(condition){
editor.putString("session_value", required_Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [shared-preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) to save your value. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/9276996) might be useful